# SQL Server Time difference in Hours as Integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a table with StartTime and EndTime which get Inserted on Button Click .
Starttime get Inserted and EndTime also I want to compute the working hours as Integer 
when I click button for EndTime

```
tblWork
StartTime |  EndTime  |  WorkingHours
 07:04:23    13:45:20       ?

select Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Getdate( ),10 ) - '07:04:23' AS INT)
```

When I click EndTime I'm using GETDATE() from server to compute work hours 
Please help I need only Time of the day not dates

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Please show what the integer should be.

Comment: Is the type of those columns `(n)varchar` or [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql)?

Comment: What happens if your workday spans across midnight? Without the `date` component, you can't properly calculate the elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes SQL Server based on the syntax.

If your definition of "workingHours" matches the definition from `datediff()` (the number of hour boundaries that have passed), then use:

```
datediff(hour, starttime, endtime) as workinghours
```

Or, if you want hours of 60 minutes, then use a small unit can calculate:

```
datediff(second, starttime, endtime) / (60 * 60) as workinghours
```

More commonly, I would suggest *decimal* hours, using:

```
datediff(second, starttime, endtime) / (60.0 * 60) as workinghours
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a8213fadfeb631065ae583bfaadf584) is an example of what these return for your data.